# AJAX Data From SharePoint List Not Carrying Over to Next Function

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, javascript, jquery, sharepoint-rest-api

I have created [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BeerusDev/kxnw80ud/108/) with mock sample data that is formatted the same way as the AJAX response data.

When I try to implement my script into a SharePoint script editor and debug it, it tells me that data is undefined outside of my `loadChartData()`

I pass the data variable through the function scope but it still returns undefined, but in the success function of my ajax call it is defined?

```
function loadChartData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: uri,
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.d != null && data.d != undefined && data.d.results.length > 0) {
                
            }
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Status: " + textStatus);
            alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
        }

    });
}
loadChartData();

$( document ).ready(function() {

function insertChartData(data) {
    var msrCount = {
        Yes: 0,
        No: 0
    };
    var trCount = {
        Yes: 0,
        No: 0
    };
    var mmCount = {
        Yes: 0,
        No: 0
    };


    for (i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {
        if (data[i].Deliverable === "MSR") {
            switch (data[i].Retained) {
                case 'Yes':
                    msrCount.Yes++;
                    break;
                case 'No':
                    msrCount.No++;
                    break;
            }
            //console.log(msrCount);
        }
        if (data[i].Deliverable === "Trip Report") {
            switch (data[i].Retained) {
                case 'Yes':
                    trCount.Yes++;
                    break;
                case 'No':
                    trCount.No++;
                    break;
            }
        }
        if (data[i].Deliverable === "Meeting Minutes") {
            switch (data[i].Retained) {
                case 'Yes':
                    mmCount.Yes++;
                    break;
                case 'No':
                    mmCount.No++;
                    break;
            }
        }

    }

    const totMSRCount = (msrCount.Yes + msrCount.No);
    const totTRCount = (trCount.Yes + trCount.No);
    const totMMCount = (mmCount.Yes + mmCount.No);

    var completeMSRCount = ((msrCount.Yes / totMSRCount) * 100).toFixed(2);
    var completeTRCount = ((trCount.Yes / totTRCount) * 100).toFixed(2);
    var completeMMCount = ((mmCount.Yes / totMMCount) * 100).toFixed(2);

    var barMSR = new ProgressBar.Circle(container, {
        color: '#aaa',
        // This has to be the same size as the maximum width to
        // prevent clipping
        strokeWidth: 4,
        trailWidth: 1,
        easing: 'easeInOut',
        duration: 1400,
        text: {
            autoStyleContainer: false
        },
        from: {
            color: '#aaa',
            width: 1
        },
        to: {
            color: '#333',
            width: 4
        },
        // Set default step function for all animate calls
        step: function(state, circle) {

            var value = Math.round(circle.value() * 100);
            if (value === 0) {
                circle.setText('');
            } else {
                circle.setText(value + "%");
            }
            if (value <= 50) {
                circle.path.setAttribute('stroke', 'red');
                circle.path.setAttribute('stroke-width', state.width);
            }
            if (value > 50 && value <= 75) {
                circle.path.setAttribute('stroke', 'yellow');
                circle.path.setAttribute('stroke-width', state.width);
            }
            if (value > 75) {
                circle.path.setAttribute('stroke', 'green');
                circle.path.setAttribute('stroke-width', state.width);
            }
        }
    });
    barMSR.text.style.fontFamily = '"Raleway", Helvetica, sans-serif';
    barMSR.text.style.fontSize = '2rem';

    barMSR.animate(msrCount.Yes / totMSRCount);

    var barTR = new ProgressBar.Circle(container1, {
        color: '#aaa',
        // This has to be the same size as the maximum width to
        // prevent clipping
        strokeWidth: 4,
        trailWidth: 1,
        easing: 'easeInOut',
        duration: 1400,
        text: {
            autoStyleContainer: false
        },
        from: {
            color: '#aaa',
            width: 1
        },
        to: {
            color: '#333',
            width: 4
        },
        // Set default step function for all animate calls
        step: function(state, circle) {

            var value = Math.round(circle.value() * 100);
            if (value === 0) {
                circle.setText('');
            } else {
                circle.setText(value + "%");
            }
            if (value <= 50) {
                circle.path.setAttribute('stroke', 'red');
                circle.path.setAttribute('stroke-width', state.width);
            }
            if (value > 50 && value <= 75) {
                circle.path.setAttribute('stroke', 'yellow');
                circle.path.setAttribute('stroke-width', state.width);
            }
            if (value > 75) {
                circle.path.setAttribute('stroke', 'green');
                circle.path.setAttribute('stroke-width', state.width);
            }
        }
    });
    barTR.text.style.fontFamily = '"Raleway", Helvetica, sans-serif';
    barTR.text.style.fontSize = '2rem';

    barTR.animate(trCount.Yes / totTRCount);

    var barMM = new ProgressBar.Circle(container2, {
        color: '#aaa',
        // This has to be the same size as the maximum width to
        // prevent clipping
        strokeWidth: 4,
        trailWidth: 1,
        easing: 'easeInOut',
        duration: 1400,
        text: {
            autoStyleContainer: false
        },
        from: {
            color: '#aaa',
            width: 1
        },
        to: {
            color: '#333',
            width: 4
        },
        // Set default step function for all animate calls
        step: function(state, circle) {
            var value = Math.round(circle.value() * 100);
            if (value === 0) {
                circle.setText('');
            } else {
                circle.setText(value + "%");
            }
            if (value <= 50) {
                circle.path.setAttribute('stroke', 'red');
                circle.path.setAttribute('stroke-width', state.width);
            }
            if (value > 50 && value <= 75) {
                circle.path.setAttribute('stroke', 'yellow');
                circle.path.setAttribute('stroke-width', state.width);
            }
            if (value > 75) {
                circle.path.setAttribute('stroke', 'green');
                circle.path.setAttribute('stroke-width', state.width);
            }
        }
    });
    barMM.text.style.fontFamily = '"Raleway", Helvetica, sans-serif';
    barMM.text.style.fontSize = '2rem';

    barMM.animate(mmCount.Yes / totMMCount);

    $('#undr_txt1').html("Retained: (" + msrCount.Yes + ") | " + "Not Retained: (" + msrCount.No + ")");
    $('#undr_txt2').html("Retained: (" + trCount.Yes + ") | " + "Not Retained: (" + trCount.No + ")");
    $('#undr_txt3').html("Retained: (" + mmCount.Yes + ") | " + "Not Retained: (" + mmCount.No + ")");
}
insertChartData();
});
```

Here is the local scope of my success:

[image]

Why can't I access it?

Comment: Where are you calling `loadChartData()` function? Are you calling `insertChartData()` function from `success` of `loadChartData()` function?

Comment: Check my updated code, I added all

Comment: Is it complete code? Where are you calling loadChartData() function? I don't see any calling between `loadChartData()` & `insertChartData()` functions?

Comment: If I call it before insertChartData() it still says Data is undefined

Comment: Complete code has been added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, the problem is that when you *define* your `insertChartData` function, you are saying you are *expecting* it to get `data` passed in, but when you actually *call* it, you are not passing anything to the function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // putting insertChartData(data) here does not pass data into the function.
    // this is the function definition, so what it is saying is that
    // the function is _expecting_ to get data passed in _when it is called_.
    // again, this is the part where you are defining the function, not actually
    // calling and executing it
    function insertChartData(data) {
        //
        // all your code in the function
        // ...
    }

    // here is where you are _calling_ insertChartData() to start it executing,
    // but you are not passing anything into it when you call it.  you should be
    // calling it like: insertChartData(someData)
    insertChartData();
});
```

The reason your fiddle works is that you define `data` as a variable in the global scope, so it is accessible from anywhere in your code, but after your `$.ajax` call, the `data` returned from SharePoint is only accessible in the *local* scope of your `success` function. (See your own screenshot: it says "Scope -> Local")

```
success: function (data) {
    if (data.d != null && data.d != undefined && data.d.results.length > 0) {
        // data here is not a global variable, it only exists
        // within the scope of this success function unless you
        // either store it in some globally available place
        // or pass it to another function. so what you should
        // probably do is, right here inside the success function
        // once you have the data:

        // pass the data to your function that is expecting it
        insertChartData(data);
    }
},
```

What I would do is

```
// define loadChartData in the global scope so it is accessible from anywhere

function loadChartData() {
    var uri = // whatever your uri is
    $.ajax({
        url: uri,
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.d != null && data.d != undefined && data.d.results.length > 0) {:
                // pass the data to your function that is expecting it
                insertChartData(data);
            }
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Status: " + textStatus);
            alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}

// define insertChartData in the global scope so it is accessible from anywhere

function insertChartData(data) {
    //
    // all your code in the function
    // ...
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    // start off the chain of events by calling
    loadChartData();

    // once loadChartData's success function _has_ the data, 
    // it will pass it to your insertChartData function
});
```

---

To address your comment on the other answer:

> It works until I get to the first if statement inside my for loop.
> Tells me (Cannot read property 'Deliverable' of undefined)

That's because you are trying to index directly into `data`, but `data` is not the array, `data.d.results` is the array.

You'll either have to change all of the places where you have

```
data[i]
```

to be

```
data.d.results[i]
```

or (because that will end up with some long, difficult to read code), just put `data.d.results` into another shorter named variable, and use that:

```
var results = data.d.results;

for (i = 0; i < results; i++) {
    if (results[i].Deliverable === "MSR") {
        switch (results[i].Retained) {
            case 'Yes':
                msrCount.Yes++;
                break;
            case 'No':
                msrCount.No++;
                break;
        }
    }

    // etc, etc...
}
```

Comment: When creating an item object to post to a SharePoint task list, what is the proper way to create the item that you set as data? I keep getting a 400 error and I think it is because of my AssignedTo value but I am not 100% sure how to assign that value as I cannot find any documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Follow below pattern for code to work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var endpointUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListName')/items";
    loadChartData(endpointUrl);
});

function loadChartData(uri) {
    $.ajax({
        url: uri,
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.d && data.d.results && data.d.results.length) {
                insertChartData(data);
            }
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}

function insertChartData(data) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works until I get to the first if statement inside my for loop. Tells me (Cannot read property 'Deliverable' of undefined)

Comment: @BeerusDev addressed your comment here in my answer